# Distance in SQL using Distance()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, spatial

I'm trying to get the points in a database that are at a distance of no more than 200 meters away, and i'm using the following code but it also retrieves all the points in the data base

```
var pin = from pinsA in db.PINS
                  .Where(p => p.PRIVACY == 0 || p.USER_ID == userId
                         && (double)currentPoint.Distance(p.location) < 200.0)
                  .Select(pr => new { pr.PIN_ID, pr.TYPE, pr.location }) 
          select new { pinsA.PIN_ID, pinsA.TYPE, pinsA.location } ;
```

Comment: What does p.Privacy == 0 means. Is it supposed to include or exclude the point from the selection.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide the specific conditions but I think you are missing parenthesis in your `Where` clause, try:

```
Where((p => p.PRIVACY == 0 || p.USER_ID == userId)
      && (double)currentPoint.Distance(p.location) < 200.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although its a preference thing, I'm not sure on the need to mix-match the query "languages" (which probably isn't helping), nor the need for a "double" select.

I also agree with **jnovo's** post on that you are most likely missing parenthesis in your where clause, but try either of the following:

Option 1:

```
var pinsWithin200 = from pins in db.Pins
                    where ((pins.PRIVACY == 0 || pins.USER_ID == userId) && pins.location.Distance(currentPoint) <= 200)
                    select new
                    {
                        PIN_ID = pins.PIN_ID,
                        TYPE = pins.TYPE,
                        location = pins.location
                    };

var results = pinsWithin200.ToList();
```

Option 2:

```
var pinsWithin200 = db.Pins
                    .Where(p => (p.PRIVACY == 0 || p.USER_ID == userId) && p.location.Distance(currentPoint) <= 200)
                    .Select(p => new
                    {
                        PIN_ID = p.PIN_ID,
                        TYPE = p.TYPE,
                        location = p.location
                    };

var results = pinsWithin200.ToList();
```

Whichever you prefer, they are cleaner, and without the double-select. Also note its good practise to explicitly name your properties in anonymous types.